# Counting frequency of a string

Tags: java, arrays, string, return

I essentially want to search the frequency of a string. For example, if I pass in the word "I", then the frequency of the word in the following sentence: "**I** went to the beach and **I** saw three people" should be 2. I've constructed such method in which I take a text (of any length), split it into an array by the white space, and loop through the array, searching if each index matches the word. Then, I increment the frequency counter and return the number as a string. Here's the method:

```
private int freq() {
String text = "I went to the beach and I saw three people";
String search = "I";
String[] splitter = text.split("\\s+");
int counter = 0;
   for (int i=0; i<splitter.length; i++)
   {
       if (splitter[i]==search) 
       {
           counter++;
       }
       else
       {

       }
   }
   return counter;
       }

}
```

This is outside the method:

```
String final = Integer.toString(freq());
System.out.println(final);
```

But as I run this, I keep getting 0 as the result. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: You're all correct! What a waste of a question :(.

Comment: You got a good HashMap out of it :) Seriously, knowing the basic data structures and when to use them is huge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `equals` instead of `==`

```
if (text[i].equals(search) )
   {
       counter++;
   }
```

**better solution**

Use a Map to map the words `Map<String,Integer>`  with frequency.

```
String [] words = line.split(" ");

Map<String,Integer> frequency = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

for (String word:words){

    Integer f = frequency.get(word);
    //checking null
    if(f==null) f=0;
    frequency.put(word,f+1);
}
```

Then you can find out for a particular word with:

```
frequency.get(word)
```

Comment: I started writing a comment about log(N) time being used, then realized the Map was instantiated as an interface (doesn't work). I changed this to a concrete type. Two common Map implementations are TreeMap and HashMap. TreeMap is log(N) time, but you can have everything sorted. HashMap will give you O(1) insertion and O(1) lookup.

Answer (score 2):

Use `equals()` method to compare string.

```
if(text[i].equals(search))
{
   counter++;
}
```

Comment: I guess his logic is incorrect too! he/she should be traversing thru "splitter" not text :)

Comment: that was a typo. I am traversing through splitter

Answer (score 1):

```
private int freq() {
    String text = "I went to the beach and I saw three people";
    String search = "I";
    String[] splitter = text.split("\\s+");
    int counter = 0;
/* problem: You want to be looping over splitter. */
    for (int i=0; i<text.length; i++)
    {
/* problem: splitter[i].equals(search) */
        if (text[i]==search)
        {   
            counter++;
        }   
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For you code to work follow the other answers, use a .equals instead of ==, but you could also use apache commons lang:

```
StringUtils.countMatches(text, search);
```

http://commons.apache.org/lang/
http://commons.apache.org/lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#countMatches(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.CharSequence)

Answer (score 0):

Strings should be compared with String.equals, not ==, which checks to see if they're the same *object*, not if they haber the same *contents*.

Answer (score 0):

To compare two `String` you have to use the `equals()` method and not a simple `==`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Map to put word as key and frequency of the word as value. Then inside the loop, try using try-catch block to add+1 to key associate with the current word (tryblock), if the word doesn't found "fdist.get(w)" will give nullpointerexception, then catch with simply put 1 for the value.

```
Map<String,Integer> fdist = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
for(String w:s.split(" ")){
    try {
        fdist.put(word, fdist.get(w)+1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fdist.put(word, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer should contain an explanation of your code and a description how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Determine the frequency of words in a file.
This is basic code for hashmap in java

```
File f = new File(fileName);
 Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
   Map<String, Integer> counts =
  new Map<String, Integer>();
      while( s.hasNext() ){
 String word = s.next();
 if( !counts.containsKey( word ) )
 counts.put( word, 1 );
else
 counts.put( word, 
    counts.get(word) + 1 ); 
}
```