# How to check number of instances of a domain in a text file

Tags: java

I have a text file containing domains like

```
ABC.COM
ABC.COM
DEF.COM
DEF.COM
XYZ.COM
```

i want to read the domains from the text file and check how many instances of domains are there.
Reading from a text file is easy but i am confused at how to check number of instances of domains.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    List<String> domains=new ArrayList<String>(); // values from your file
    domains.add("abc.com");
    domains.add("abc.com");
    domains.add("xyz.com");
   //added for example
    Map<String,Integer> domainCount=new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for(String domain:domains){
        if(domainCount.containsKey(domain)){
            domainCount.put(domain, domainCount.get(domain)+1);
        }else
            domainCount.put(domain, new Integer(1));

    }
    Set<Entry<String, Integer>> entrySet = domainCount.entrySet();
    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : entrySet) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Split by space (String instances have method `split`), iterate through result array and use `Map<String(domainName), Integer(count)>` - when domain is in map, than increase count in map by 1, when not - put domain name in map and set 1 as a value.

Answer (score 1):

Better solution is to use a Map to map the words Map with frequency.

`Map<String,Integer> frequency = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();`

- Read file

  ```
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("infilename"));
  String str;
  while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
      buildMap(str);
  }
  in.close();
  ```
- Build map method : You can split the  urls in your [file by reading them line by line](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/readlinesfromfile.html) and splitting with delimiter(in your case space).

  ```
  String [] words = line.split(" ");   
  for (String word:words){
      Integer f = frequency.get(word);
      if(f==null) f=0;
      frequency.put(word,f+1);
  }
  ```
- Find out for a particular domain with:

  `frequency.get(domainName)`

Ref: [Counting frequency of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7830712/607637)

Comment: You should test that `f` is not null, else you will get an NPE the first time a word is met.

Answer (score 0):

If the domains are unknown you can do something like:

```
// Field Declaration
private Map<String, Integer> mappedDomain = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
private static final List<String> domainList = new ArrayList<String>();
// Add all that you want to track
domainList.add("com");
domainList.add("net");
domainList.add("org");
...

// Inside the loop where you do a readLine
String[] words = line.split(" ");
for (String word : words) {

  String[] wordSplit = word.split(".");

  if (wordSplit.length == 2) {

    for (String domainCheck : domainList) {

      if (domainCheck.equals(wordSplit[1])) {

        if (mappedDomain.containsKey(word)) {
          mappedDomain.put(word, mappedDomain.get(word)+1);
        } else {
          mappedDomain.put(word, 1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> Note: This will work for something like xxx.xxx; if you need to take care of complex formats you need to modify the logic from wordSplit!